# JavaFX Combobox: handling key pressed for enter

Tags: javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

i want to change the focus if a user press ENTER in a combobox. Firstly, i used an action-listener, but this will be also triggered when a user changes its value by pressing arrow key up or down or selecting value in the dropdown.

Therefore i thought that i could solve that by registering a key handler. But it doesn't work for the ENTER key.

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Edit:

Sorry i thought that my intro is enough.

So i have little form with some textfields and a comboBox. To increase the usability, the user only needs to press enter to switch to next field. This works great for textfields:

```
textfield.setOnAction(e -> {
        cmbTax.requestFocus();
});
```

But if i register an action-listener, it would not fulfill my requirements, because it will be always triggered when value is changed:

```
cmbTax.setOnAction(e->textfield2.requestFocus());
```

So i tried a key listener, but it didn't react on ENTER, because it is handled internal before my listener would be called:

```
cmbTax.getEditor().setOnKeyPressed(this::handleKeyPressedForComboBox);
```

regards

Comment: Post [mcve], show what you have done so far and descibe where you have problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) { 
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
});
```

In your case:

```
cmbTax.setOnKeyPressed(this::handleKeyPressedForComboBox);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem. But i think it is a very strange behaviour. I registered the key listener on the editor, because i want also to listen on pressing arrow key down and this didn't worked. But no matter i registered it twice at the end.